# libGDX ApplicationListener not found

Tags: java, libgdx

Hey right now i'm making a 2D game, for the desktop and Android. I installed libGDX because i heard that it made developing a game in java easier. But when i run the desktop code it shows up with this error
`java: cannot access com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener
  class file for com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener not found` This is the Main code that i'm running:

```
    package com.rare.Forms;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;




public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "MyGame";
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.width = 480;
        cfg.height = 320;

        new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

I've tried installing the library, multiple times but it always shows the same error.
I would be very greatfull you someone could help me.
Ohh and sorry for the bad english, it isn't my birth language.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? IF you are the look at this: http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/
This should help you.

Comment: No im not using Eclipse, im using Intellij. but i will take a look. Thanks

Comment: Hey i that website helped out. What is did was loading it into Eclipse, where there were no errors. Then i imported it into Intellij and now it works without errors, and i can finally start developing my game now. Thank you.

Comment: i added it as an aswer so you can mark it as accepted and solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
The original answer is no longer valid, as the linked tutorial does not exist anymore and LibGDX has changed quite a bit since then.
There is now an [official documentation on how to setup the environment](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation/gettingstarted/Setting%20Up.html).
Note, that Android Studio or IntelliJ is recommended, as it is the only IDE to officially support Android.

<s>I am posting it as an answer that you can mark it as solved and it can help others in future.
If you are using Eclipse the setup in [this](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/) tutorial should help you. If you are using intellij you can load the project in eclipse do this setup and then import it to intellij. I am sure that you can do the things also in intellij without eclipse but i don't know intellij so i can't help you with this.</s>

Comment: Tutorial link is broken with a 404

Comment: @broken-e thank you for the information, I updated the answer.