# Setting up a LibGDX project in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, crash, libgdx

I'm developing an Android game in Java, using the LibGDX framework.
I really want to use the Idea IDE, so I've followed [the official tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IntelliJIDEALibgdx) on setting up the project.
At first, there doesn't not seem to be a problem. When I make an output artifacts, the executable .jar file runs flawlessly on my desktop. The problems emerge with the Android .apk file. When I try to run it in emulator, it crashes with the error: "unfortunately "AppName" has stopped working".

1. I don't think the problem is in my code, since I didn't write any. I only have the starter classes and they are just copied from the tutorial above.
2. I'm not sure if it works outside the emulator, since I don't currently have a real android device to test it on.

Do you have any idea what might be the cause of this strange behavior?

Comment: It might be a problem with the exported libraries. Please make sure that the gdx.jar and the android backend jars are exported to your .apk (you can unzip it and check that)

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524776/libgdx-applicationlistener-not-found/21528044#21528044
He solved his issue, by creating the project in eclipse and exporting/importing it to intellij. I am sure you can do this things in IntelliJ but i have never used it.

Comment: You might be right, I can't see them anywhere inside! Only armeabi and armeabi-v7a are inside the lib folder of my .apk. How do I add the gdx.jar?

Comment: @BasomtiKombucha if you ever succeeded in this, please post it here